# Pip3 cannot find/install modules

Tags: python, pip, operating-system, python-3.5, shelve

I'm trying to install packages in Python using pip3.  I've definitely managed to install these packages on other systems, so I know they exist.  But it's as if the pip3 repository I'm using doesn't contain then.  The packages are shelve and os.  The error I get is along the lines of:

```
    [root@host]# pip3 install shelve
Collecting shelve
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shelve (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for shelve
```

I'm using RHEL 7 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[The project](https://pypi.org/project/shelve/) has one release in 2011 and the release doesn't have downloadable files. Not a useable project by all accounts.

Do you mean [shelve from the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)? You don't need to install it, it's always available, just import it.

Answer (score 0):

you cal also use for example for install tkinter package :

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk; if you have python installed
```

or you can use :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk; if you have python3 installed
```